# Using JavaScript to Un-Populate Form in Email Forward

Tags: javascript, forms, email

My organization directs users to a form whose fields successfully pre-populate with user information when they access the form via a URL we email to them.  The URL contains a unique identifier for each recipient that corresponds to their record in our info system.

Due to privacy considerations, we want this form NOT to pre-populate if the intended recipient of the URL forwards the email to a friend.  Moreover, we need the user's unique ID in the URL disabled altogether so that the form doesn't overwrite the original user's record with the friend's information upon submission.

I don't have access to the source code of this form.  However, the form builder does allow for custom JavaScript.  Unfortunately, my office doesn't know a lot of JavaScript, and we don't really have a dev team.

So, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anyway to flag their record as having been used in the back end system?

Comment: There is, but 1) we want them to be able to resubmit the form on an as-needed basis to update their info, so we want the intended recipient to always have access to it, and 2) if the intended recipient sends it straight to another person without ever clicking the link, we want the form to pick up on that.

Comment: That begs the question, how do you intend to differentiate between a new submission by a friend, a resubmission / update and the original user forwarding it to another address they control eg work email to personal email